# WordPress custom query sanitization or security

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I am trying to create a custom query in WordPress.

here is how I am creating the custom query.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->posts} WHERE 1=1";
foreach ($filters as $filter) {
        $filter = (array) $filter;
        $col_name = sanitize_text_field($filter['col_name']);
        $operator = $filter['operator'];
        $value = $filter['value'];

        $query .= " AND {$col_name} {$operator} '{$value}'";
    }
```

in the `$filters` array i have values something like this.

```
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [col_name] => id
            [operator] => =
            [value] => 1
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [col_name] => id
            [operator] => =
            [value] => 2
        )

)
```

If I print the `$query` variable I get the query string like this.

`SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE 1=1 AND id = '1' AND id = '2'`

If you see that with `$col_name` i have used the `sanitize_text_field` function in order to prevent the parameter from being used inappropriately.

My question is that is this enqugh to use `sanitize_text_field` and prevent the query being hacked or do i need to take care more?

I am using custom query becase I do have some custom requirements.

Answer (score 0):

it is better to use the methods available in the wpdb class.

you can use [wp database model](https://packagist.org/packages/alirezadehkar/wp-database-model) composer package